# Sharing files between 2 different routers

Tags: networking, router, file-sharing

I realize this has been asked before and I have read as much as I could find on the topic but I still need help with this because there are so many different approaches and the ones I am trying aren't working.

So I have 2 routers, lets call them A and B. Both have a wireless feature and are active. A is in the basement and receives the internet. There is a TV on the ground floor that is connected to A through an ethernet wire. B is upstairs and gets the internet from A through an ethernet wire. Connected to B, is a desktop running Plex Media Server.

What I want to do is make sure devices connected to both routes can access the Plex Media Server.

So what I have read is that I should plug in the ethernet wire connecting B to a into a LAN port instead of the WAN port. After that I should turn off DHCP. I have tried this and B stops receiving internet. What am I doing wrong?

Another thing I have read is to use Router B in bridge mode but Router B is running openwrt and I have QoS on it so gaming/VoIP/browsing is unaffected by heavy downloading/uploading. I would prefer to keep this active. I realize it might be ineffective if a device in Router A is doing some hardcore downloading but all that stuff is done on Router B anyway so it doesn't matter. Router A can't get openwrt because it is a shitty one provided by Bell.

So, how do I proceed with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you plug into a LAN port and turn off DHCP on B, you need to give it:

- an address on the A router (B's LAN address - probably by default they are both 192.168.1.1, given how common that is, and they can't be the same if they are on the same network.)
- Router A's address as the gateway address of its LAN settings (which probably defaults to itself.)

If not, it won't work.

If we assume a typical dreadful default setup (which may not match your actual default setup - feel free to post more details about what the settings actually are) you would have both routers set to 192.168.1.1 and both handing out 192.168.1.100-254 for DHCP (or 192.168.2-254 for the most dreadful default of DHCP.)

These settings can, and should, be changed.

Keeping the changes minimal:

- Leave A at 192.168.1.1
- Set A's DHCP to 192.168.1.100-150, unless you really expect more than 50 devices.
- Set B's LAN address to 192.168.1.10, and its gateway to 192.168.1.1
- turn off DHCP on B *or* let B hand out 151-200 (make sure it hands out 192.168.1.1 (or whatever A is set to) as the gateway, as well)

Comment: Ok doing this worked except for one major flaw.. I can no longer access router B's configuration page! I set the lan address to 192.168.1.2 because A is .1 so B would make sense to be .2 for me. I have 2 options to access it how ever neither are long term solutions. What IP would I have to set to access it?

Comment: It should be accessible at 192.168.1.2, if that's what you set it to; unless something else is already set to 192.168.1.2 - in which case any other address from 192.168.1.X that's not in use, or in the DHCP range you have set, should work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are attempting to use two routers, when there really is only a need for one router and one switch.  I understand that you enjoy the use of the QOS features on Router B.  Router B sounds like it is a home router with a switch built in.  I would place that in the basement connected to the ISP provided router.  Where router B currently is, I would consider using a cheap switch like [http://www.amazon.com/TRENDnet-Unmanaged-GREENnet-Standard-1000Mbps/dp/B001QUA6RA/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1382236094&sr=8-3&keywords=switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001QUA6RA)
This solution would provide one network where all devices are on the same subnet and would be able to easily see each other.  I understand that this requires a 20 something dollar investment, but I think it would work much better for you.

Comment: The problem is that Router A has crappy wifi and everyone using wifi is mostly upstairs. Router B has to be upstairs so everyone gets good wifi receptiom. I will eventually replace the basement one with a router of my own but I can't afford it right now.

Comment: is it out of the question to run a second ethernet cable back down to the basement where you can connect a switch down there?

Comment: Yes unfortunately it is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Router B as your main and Router A has to be in dumb modem mode.
The way you do this is:

1) Router B <--> Router A Wan-to-Lan wired connection

2) insert PPPoE information in router "B". in which case, router B handles everything, PPPoE to the internet, and internal DHCP

optional: disable DHCP and Wifi On router A. no clients should directly connect to router/modem A.